# Bind form control to quill editor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, quill

I'm using Quill editor using div to render it on html component

```
  <div id="editor-container" #quilled style="height:350px"></div>
```

in ts file

```
  @ViewChild('quilled') quilled : ElementRef; 


 Quill.register('modules/imageDropAndPaste', QuillImageDropAndPaste)
    this.quitinns = new Quill('#editor-container', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: 
        [
          [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
          ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
          [{ 'list': "ordered" }, { 'list': "bullet" }, { 'indent': "-1" }, { 'indent': "+1" }],
          [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
          [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }], 
          ["link", "image", "blockquote"],["table"]
      ],
        imageDropAndPaste: {
          handler: this.fileimageHandler.bind(this),
        },
      },
      placeholder: 'Copy & paste, or drag an image here...',
      readOnly: false,
      theme: 'snow',
    })
```

i want to bind  `formControlName="content"` to editor and caLL `(blur)` event on quill editor

Any solution